# jQuery datepicker and autocomplete together

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am new to Jquery and Javascripts.

I have two items on a jsp page (Index.jsp). One text item 'Vendor Name' is to 'autocomplete' when I type alphabets and other text item is to accept 'Bill Date' using Jquery Datepicker.

I tried to invoke another jsp (getdata.jsp) as soon as I start typing alphabets to auto populate Vendor names that are stored in database. This feature is working with out any issue.

But when I include 'Bill Date' item also in Index.Jsp, auto complete is not working but date picker is working. Please let me know how to do auto complete and date picker.

Please note that required libraries are downloaded and kept in my working directory and there is no issue with library paths.

### Index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery.autocomplete.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){    
        $("#billdate").datepicker(
                                    {
                               inline:true,
                                       showOn: "button",
                                       buttonImageOnly: true,
                                       buttonImage: "From_Date_Calendar.jpg",
                                       dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
                             });
            });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
    bill Date <input type="text" id="billdate" readonly /><br/> 

        <script>
           $("#country").autocomplete("getdata.jsp");
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### getdata.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="BillmgmtPack.DummyDB"%>
<%
         System.out.println("In get data.jsp"); 
    DummyDB db = new DummyDB();

    String query = request.getParameter("q");

    List<String> countries = db.getData(query);

    Iterator<String> iterator = countries.iterator(); 

    while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
        String country = (String)iterator.next();
        out.println(country);
    }  
%>
```

### DummyDB.java

```
package BillmgmtPack;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*; 
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.*;

import javax.naming.*;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class DummyDB {

    public List<String> getData(String query) {
        String country = null;
        query = query.toLowerCase();
            Connection con=null;
        List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();

            try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
         con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:1521:qqqqq","yyyyy","zzzzz"); 
            }catch(Exception e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } 
                try{
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select vendor_name from vendor_master where vendor_name like upper('"+query+"%')");
        //System.out.println("rs query-"+query);

        int k=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
                //System.out.println("in rs query-"+query+"   / "+rs.getString(1));
        matched.add(rs.getString(1));
                k=k+1;
            } 
                    if (k==0)
                    {
                        matched.add("notfound");
                    }    
            }        catch(Exception e)
                     {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } 

        return matched;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery autocomplete is also the name of a widget in jQuery ui. Maybe jQuery ui comes to replace the other aucomplete, thus preventing the operation of the first.

I suggest you to delete the 1st autocomplete and use that of jQuery ui referring to the [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete)

Comment: Deleted separate 'autocomplete' and kept only 'jquery ui'. Still no use

Comment: The 2 widgets do not work the same way. Did you go to the documentation to see the options that needed to be changed (the **source** option for example) ?